# How does tcp socket's read method work?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Currently I come across a situation that I would like to read the inputstream to a byte array which only contains a single byte. I repeat to do this for a certain number of times to make sure I get the corresponding length of bytes. For example,read 40 times for 40 bytes. But in the other side of this socket, it writes 512 bytes in each write method.(Actually in the most cases the read buffer is 512 bytes,just in a certain condition I read one byte a time). I am wondering in this case if the sending socket still writes 512 bytes over the network each time and the receiving socket receives all of them and stores them in a local byte array and the read method reads a single byte each time from the local array or the sending socket writes only 1 byte each time as well? This question may sound kind of confused,Hopefully I made it clear.Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blocks until some data is available in the kernel's socket receive buffer, and then transfers as many bytes as are available.

Comment: Does this mean that even if the the read method only fills a single byte array each time, the receiving socket may have already received 512 bytes and calling read method 40 times will not trigger 40 times write method being called in the sending socket?

Comment: "and then transfers as many bytes as are available." sounds a little bit confused to me. Do you mean the kernel's receive buffer will get reset for  new input stream data no matter how many bytes the read method fills to a byte array?

Comment: @user1870797 (1) Calling the read method doesn't 'trigger the write method'. The sending application calls the write method. (2) It is the wording 'reset for new input stream data no matter how many bytes the read method fills to a byte array' that is confused. I have no idea what you are talking about here, starting with the word 'reset'.

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate expression. My English is not good. The 'reset' is kind of like allocating a new receive buffer here. So each time when you call read,now matter how many bytes you read, the receive buffer got cleared and allocated a new empty array.

Comment: I think previously I have misunderstood your answer. Today I wrote a test application which made me find that it seems all the bytes received are stored in the receive buffer. and the read method has nothing to do how much bytes the sending socket writes like you said. So frequently call read to fill a single byte array will not cause frequent network communication. It just reads the local receive buffer.